Anaconda environment not activating even when everything is fine
I have a anaconda installed on my windows 11 desktop with python version 3.10. All my environment and path variables are attached. However when I am trying to create a virtual environment in anaconda and activating it, this is not getting activated.
As you can see in this image
I have tried reinstalling it and adding path variables again but nothing works, can someone give a solution to this?
